# moving a structure from 32-bit to 64-bit in C programming language

Tags: c, 32bit-64bit

My problem is, I want to move a structure form 32-bits space to 64-bits space.

Suppose I declare same structure in 64-bits space with same fields, is there a way to copy the corresponding fields from 32-bit to 64-bit structure ?

let me introduce to the actual problem, this is related to caching stuff, we have limited size on ram that is a 32 bit space, so if we have 1G space on ram and my structure size for a single cached object is 1M then the number of objects i can store is limited to 1G/1M. therefore to solve this probem i want to declare my structure in 64 bits spcace (so that there is no spcace crunch ) and number of objects can be incrased to infinite practically

suppose we have a structure in 32 bit space

```
typedef struct x{
int a ;
int *b ;
} x_t;
```

now i want to move this structure in 64 bit space, remove the 32 bit space structure.

```
typedef struct x_64{
    int a ;
    int *b ;
    } x_64_t;
```

so, if previously my variables were accessed like x->b or x.a, how can i make sure the same values are transmitted to 64 bit structure, without the change in functionality of entire code.

One method can be to have a buffer in 64bit space, for every access of variable in 32bit space go to 64 write/read into the buffer. but that is a tedious process, can there be some alternative ??

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow, you might want to show us a little bit of code with what you are trying to do, because currently it is quite unclear what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: let me introduce to the actual problem, this is related to caching stuff, we have limited size on ram that is a 32 bit space, so if we have 1G space on ram and my structure size for a single cached object is 1M then the number of objects i can store is limited to 1G/1M. therefore to solve this probem i want to declare my structure in 64 bits spcace (so that there is no spcace crunch ) and number of objects can be incrased to infinite practically.

Comment: Please update the question, other users with your specifc question will look for information there, not in the comments.

Comment: thanks for advice, did you get the problem ??

Answer (score 4):

You can copy data just fine between 32-bit and 64-bit, provided you use compatible data types.

For example, the structure:

```
struct xyzzy {
    int a;
    int b;
}
```

won't be compatible if your `int` types are of different widths in the 32-bit and 64-bit world.

C99 provided fixed width types such as `int32_t` which are meant to be the same size regardless of platform. If your compiler is compliant, it is required to provide those types if it has an *actual* type of that size.

Failing that, you can often change your source code so that these problems are minimised, such as with:

```
#ifdef INT_IS_64BITS
    typedef int my_64bit_type;
#endif

#ifdef LONG_IS_64BITS
    typedef long my_64bit_type;
#endif

my_64bit_type xyzzy;
```

and compile with a suitable definition:

```
gcc -DLONG_IS_64BITS myprog.c
```

Comment: what makes you think this question is about a 32-/64-bit _architecture_?

Comment: My best (educated) guess, given the available info. Until OP clarifies, not much more to go on.